# How to send repeating data from all symfony's controller routes to twig?

Tags: php, twig, symfony

Here is the use case:

I have a simple [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) with a simple [dropdown](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) menu.
I have a list of cities in the Database with the name of the cities. I want to get all the cities and add them to the dropdown menu.

Simple way is to send additional data, like array of cities to twig. But i have a lot of routes and i don't think that this is good to repeat fetching every time. This is not good, right?

```
 public function testpageAction(){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $cities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:City')->findAll();
        return $this->render('appviews/testpage.html.twig',array('cities'=>$cities));
    }
```

There is a [method to inject variable into all templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html), but this is static data, so it is not the solution.

There is a plan in my head to make a method that will be run before controller methods and it will send the data to those methods. But it does not seem good and I believe there is a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a CityController or a BaseController with method getAllCities, and embed this controller in your base template.

From Symfony [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) :

> In some cases, you need to do more than include a simple template. Suppose you have a sidebar in your layout that contains the three most recent articles. Retrieving the three articles may include querying the database or performing other heavy logic that can't be done from within a template.
>   The solution is to simply embed the result of an entire controller from your template.

Something like this:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
   public function getAllCities()
   {
       // make a database call or other logic
       // to get all cities
       $cities = ...;

       return $this->render(
           'cities.html.twig',
           array('cities' => $cities)
       );
   }
}
```

Your cities template:

```
{# app/Resources/views/cities.html.twig #}
{% for city in cities %}
    <a href="#"> {{ city}} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

And in your base template:

```
{# app/Resources/views/base.html.twig #}
<div id="sidebar">
    {{ render(controller(
       'AppBundle:Base:getAllCities'
    )) }}
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! Symfony is awesome!  Thank you very much!